# counting binary digit algorithm || prove big oh

Tags: algorithm

Is the big oh (Log n ) ? 
how can i prove it by using summation

```
  //Input: A positive decimal integer n
  //Output: The number of binary digits in n’s binary representation
  count ← 1
 while n > 1 do
 count ← count + 1
 n ← ⌊n/2⌋ 
 return count
```

Comment: I think you mean `n > 0`. I would have said it was `O(log(N)^2)` where `N` is the value (assuming it has no more bytes than needed)

Comment: Since returned `count = logN`(approx). hence proved

Answer (score 1):

The `n` is reducing like this:

```
n + n / 2 + n / 4 + n / 8 + .... + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1
```

The summation of above series is `2^(log(n)) - 1`.

Now come to the above question. The number of times the loop executed is the number of items appears in above series = time complexity of the algorithm.

The number of items appears in above series is `logn`. So the algorithm time complexity is `O(logn)`.

```
Example:
n = 8; the corresponding series:
8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15(2^4 - 1) ~ 2^4 ~ 2^logn
Here, number of items in series = 4

therefore, 
time complexity = O(number of iteration)
                = O(number of elements in series)
                = O(logn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the returned value `count`. As it would be closer to `logN`, you can state that the TC is `log(N)`.

Just think reverse way (mathematically):

```
1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8 -> ... N (xth value considering 0-indexing system)
2^x = N
x = logN
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that larger numbers use more memory and take more processing for each operation. Note: time complexity only cares what happens for the largest values not the smaller ones.

The number of iterations is `log2(n)` however the cost of the `n > 0` and `n = n / 2` is proportional to the size of the integer. i.e. 128 -bit costs twice 64-bit and 1024-bit is 16 times greater.  So the cost of each operation is `log(m)` where `m` is the maximum unsigned value which the number of bits stores.  If you assume there is a fixed wasted bits e.g. no more than 64-bit this means the cost is `O(log(n) * log(n))` or `O(log(n)^2)`

If you used Java's BigInteger, that's what the time complexity would be.

Answer (score -1):

Big Oh complexity can easily be calculated by counting number of times the while loop runs as the operations inside while loop take constant time.In this case N varies as-

```
N,N/2,N/4,N/16.... ,1
```

Just counting number of terms in above series will give me number of times loop runs.So,

```
N/2^p=1       (p is number of times loop runs)
```

This gives p=logN thus complexity O(logN)